# How to execute queries during a stream using pg-promise?

Tags: node.js, pg-promise

I'm trying to execute an insert query for each row of a query stream using pg-promise with pg-query-stream. With the approach I have, memory usage increases with each query executed.

I've also narrowed the problem down to just executing any query during the stream, not just inserts. I currently listen for 'data' events on the stream, pause the stream, execute a query, and resume the stream. I've also tried piping the query stream into a writeable stream that executes the query, but I get the error that the db connection is already closed.

```js
let count = 0;
const startTime = new Date();

const qs = new QueryStream('SELECT 1 FROM GENERATE_SERIES(1, 1000000)');

db.stream(qs, stream => {
    stream.on('data', async () => {
        count++;
        stream.pause();
        await db.one('SELECT 1');
        if (count % 10000 === 0) {
            const duration = Math.round((new Date() - startTime) / 1000);
            const mb = Math.round(process.memoryUsage().heapUsed/1024/1024);
            console.log(`row ${count}, ${mb}MB, ${duration} seconds`);
        }
        stream.resume();
    });
});
```

I expected the memory usage to hover around a constant value, but the output looks like the following:

```
row 10000, 105MB, 4 seconds
row 20000, 191MB, 6 seconds
row 30000, 278MB, 9 seconds
row 40000, 370MB, 10 seconds
row 50000, 458MB, 14 seconds
```

It takes over 10 minutes to reach row 60000.

**UPDATE:**

I edited the code above to include async/await to wait for the inner query to finish and I increased the series to 10,000,000. I ran the node process with 512MB of memory and the program slows significantly when approaching that limit but doesn't crash. This problem occurred with v10 and not v11+ of node.

Comment: Are you sure that's the extra line `db.one('SELECT 1');` that's causing the extra memory usage, and not something else? Also, where's the `.then.catch` there? It's a loose promise without.

Comment: Looked at it again and noticed the problem right away. I'm not waiting for the inner query to finish. Adding async/await fixed it. I'm still having a memory leak in my full app with lots of other logic, so I'll see if I can reduce it down to something simple and post back here.

Answer (score 0):

This is due to invalid use of promises / asynchronous code.

Line `db.one('SELECT 1');` isn't chained to anything, spawning loose promises at a fast rate, which in turn pollutes memory.

You need to chain it either with `.then.catch` or with `await`.

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer. I've updated the question based on your suggestions.